# Why referencing table two times instead of just once

Tags: sql

I don't understand why in the below query there has to be reference to zones table twice (as zpu and zdo). When I try modified query with one "zones" table instead of splitting it into zpu and zdo I have different outcome. The outcome table has to have two columns, one with pickup location and second with dropoff location. Locations are contained withing "zones" table.

Can't figure out why is that and what am I lacking in SQL mechanics.

Tables:

**Trips**

| tpep_pickup_datetime | tpep_dropoff_datetime | total_amount | PULocationID | DOLocationID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "2021-01-01 00:30:10" | "2021-01-01 00:36:12" | 11.8 | 142 | 43 |
| "2021-01-01 00:51:20" | "2021-01-01 00:52:19" | 4.3 | 238 | 151 |
| "2021-01-01 00:43:30" | "2021-01-01 01:11:06" | 51.95 | 132 | 165 |
| "2021-01-01 00:15:48" | "2021-01-01 00:31:01" | 36.35 | 138 | 132 |
| "2021-01-01 00:31:49" | "2021-01-01 00:48:21" | 24.36 | 68 | 33 |
| "2021-01-01 00:16:29" | "2021-01-01 00:24:30" | 14.15 | 224 | 68 |
| "2021-01-01 00:00:28" | "2021-01-01 00:17:28" | 17.3 | 95 | 157 |
| "2021-01-01 00:12:29" | "2021-01-01 00:30:34" | 21.8 | 90 | 40 |

**Zones**

| LocationID | Borough | Zone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EWR | Newark Airport |
| 2 | Queens | Jamaica Bay |
| 3 | Bronx | Allerton/Pelham Gardens |
| 4 | Manhattan | Alphabet City Yellow Zone |
| 5 | Staten Island | Arden Heights |
| 6 | Staten Island | Arrochar/Fort Wadsworth |
| 7 | Queens | Astoria |
| 8 | Queens | Astoria Park |
| 9 | Queens | Auburndale |
| 10 | Queens | Baisley Park |

Query

```sql
select
    tpep_pickup_datetime,
    tpep_dropoff_datetime,
    total_amount,
    CONCAT(zpu."Borough", ' / ', zpu."Zone") AS "pick_up_loc",
    CONCAT(zdo."Borough", ' / ', zpu."Zone") AS "drop_off_loc"
from
    trips t,
    zones zpu,
    zones zdo
WHERE
    t."PULocationID" = zpu."LocationID" AND
    t."DOLocationID" = zdo."LocationID"
```

**Outcome** (good table):

| tpep_pickup_datetime | tpep_dropoff_datetime | total_amount | pick_up_loc | drop_off_loc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:30:10 | 2021-01-01 00:36:12 | 11.8 | Manhattan / Lincoln Square East | Manhattan / Lincoln Square East |
| 2021-01-01 00:51:20 | 2021-01-01 00:52:19 | 4.3 | Manhattan / Upper West Side North | Manhattan / Upper West Side North |
| 2021-01-01 00:43:30 | 2021-01-01 01:11:06 | 51.95 | Queens / JFK Airport | Brooklyn / JFK Airport |
| 2021-01-01 00:15:48 | 2021-01-01 00:31:01 | 36.35 | Queens / LaGuardia Airport | Queens / LaGuardia Airport |
| 2021-01-01 00:31:49 | 2021-01-01 00:48:21 | 24.36 | Manhattan / East Chelsea | Brooklyn / East Chelsea |
| 2021-01-01 00:16:29 | 2021-01-01 00:24:30 | 14.15 | Manhattan / Stuy Town/Peter Cooper Village | Manhattan / Stuy Town/Peter Cooper Village |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:28 | 2021-01-01 00:17:28 | 17.3 | Queens / Forest Hills | Queens / Forest Hills |
| 2021-01-01 00:12:29 | 2021-01-01 00:30:34 | 21.8 | Manhattan / Flatiron | Brooklyn / Flatiron |
| 2021-01-01 00:39:16 | 2021-01-01 01:00:13 | 28.8 | Brooklyn / Fort Greene | Queens / Fort Greene |
| 2021-01-01 00:26:12 | 2021-01-01 00:39:46 | 18.95 | Manhattan / Yorkville West | Manhattan / Yorkville West |

Comment: One JOIN for pickup, and another JOIN for destination.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: On a side note: It seems you defined your table columns with explicit upper/lower case, e.g. "PULocationID". In many DBMS this forces you to always use the exact same upper/lower case and quotes for these columns. It is hence recommended to define the columns without quotes, because then you can use any upper/lower case. PULocationID would be allowed, but PuLocationId would also be fine, and so would be pulocationid and any other combination. If you want columns readable regardless of upper/lower case, use underscores: pu_location_id.

Comment: thank you @jarlh this and extensive answer from Thorsten Kettner helped me understand this completely. I wasn't looking at this as JOIN in the beginning, now with this knowledge I know what is happening :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select trips and join addresses, and you wonder why you are forced to join the addresses again and why it doesn't suffice to tell the DBMS once to get you the addresses.

This misunderstanding is probably bolstered by the ancient join syntax you are using - a syntax used in the 1980s mainly until explicit joins made it into the SQL standard in 1992.

When you join tables, you actuall join table *rows*.

With `select * from trips, zones` you join every trip row with every zone row. With eight trip rows and 10 zones you get 80 result rows. So you joined all ten zones to each trip. With `select * from trips t, zones zpu, zones zdo` you get a result of 800 rows, each trip combined with all ten zones and these again combined with all ten zones, i.e. all 100 possible zone combinations per trip.

In your query you have  `WHERE t.pulocationid = zpu.locationid AND t.dolocationid = zdo.locationid`. For one trip there is only one of its 100 intermediate result rows that match this criteria and the other 99 are dismissed.

Now, if you joined the zones table only once, you had ten rows per trip in your intermediate result, each row would contain one zone. Now to your criteria, there are two options: use `AND` or `OR`:

```
select * from trips t, zones z
where t."PULocationID" = z."LocationID" AND t."DOLocationID" = z."LocationID"
```

This would only select rows for which t.pulocationid = t.dolocationid, because the criteria demand them to both match the one zone in the joined row. In your sample data there is not a single trip where the two locations are equal. You would get an empty result set.

```
select * from trips t, zones z
where t."PULocationID" = z."LocationID" OR t."DOLocationID" = z."LocationID"
```

With this query you would get the row where the zone matches the t.pulocationid and the row where the zone matches the t.dolocationid. I.e. you would get two result rows per trip, one with the pickup zone, one with the drop off zone.

But you want one result row per trip with both zones in that same result row.

Explicit joins make this more readable:

```
select
  tpep_pickup_datetime,
  tpep_dropoff_datetime,
  total_amount,
  CONCAT(zpu."Borough", ' / ', zpu."Zone") AS "pick_up_loc",
  CONCAT(zdo."Borough", ' / ', zpu."Zone") AS "drop_off_loc"
from trips t
inner join zones zpu on zpu."LocationID" = t."PULocationID"
inner join zones zdo on zdo."LocationID" = t."DOLocationID";
```

This does exactly the same thing as your query, but it is easier to read. Take a trip, join the pickup location row, join the drop off location row.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive and perfect answer, solved.